# restore input field value on submit of form using php

Tags: php

I am working on php form submit, and i have php validation for form.

The registration page name say "page1.php" and retrieving field values in other page say "page2.php". if validation throughs error. it will redirect to other page say "page3.php" on click of any link in "page3.php" it will redirect back to registraion page i.e "page1.php" but i am not able to store or retain values entered by user. can any one suggest or guide me how to over come this,

below is the code i used.

Page2.php

```
$name = $_POST['txtname'];
$_SESSION['txtname'] = $name;
```

page1.php

```
<input type='text' name="txtname" id="txtname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtname']; ?>"/>
```

Comment: You are on right track. what was wrong with this current code ?

Comment: r u trying to show the name in form for login or something?If u want to show that value add placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtname']; ?>" inside form

Comment: i have more than 15 fields so after getting form submit i dont want user to enter all the fields again. so want to retain those values, i am using session, but still its not working.

Comment: i am trying to show the same values want was entered by user before submitting in the input field.

Comment: echo session variable in  page3.php to check whether the session is retaining value.It will ensure whether session is correctly done or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, because the `session_start()` should be in any php file you execute and want to access `SESSION` array

```
## Top of the file
<?php session_start(); ?>

## Content
<input type='text' name="txtname" id="txtname" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['txtname']) ? $_SESSION['txtname'] : ''); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
your fields in first page should be like this.

<input type='text' name="txtname" id="txtname" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['txtname'])){?> value="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtname']; ?>" <?Php }?>/>
```

In the second page if the validation is failed write your logic to redirect and in third page create links.
 `session_start()` is must in `page1.php` and `page2.php`

if you want dont want these variables after validation or some time  you can unset those session variables.

or

you can design text fields as below

```
<input type='text' name="txtname" id="txtname" <?php if($_SESSION['txtname']!=""){?> value="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtname']; ?>" <?Php }?>/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type='text' name="txtname" placeholder="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtname']; ?>" id="txtname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['txtname']; ?>"/>
```

Have you added session_start() at top of the file?

Comment: yeah Sivagopal is right.you must check whether session was set or not before assigning the value.add if(isset) condition in both value and placeholder field